# Send parameters to a JUnit test case

Tags: class, parameters, junit

I would like to send parameters to a JTestCase.

My code is :

```
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(myclass.class);
```

and I need to send it a few parameters for the test. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way `junit` will do this for you.

You will have to take care of that yourself.

You could write a static method for `myclass` that accepts the parameters and makes them available for your test methods.

Answer (score 1):

define a method with annotation @parameter in your Junit class. In that class you can get the required parameters.